# Updating git branch with missing commits

Tags: git

Let's say I have branch `feature/somethingnew` and branch `dev`

Current dev branch has the following commits (let's name letters for the example)

```
DEV ->  A-B-C-D-E
```

For the `somethingnew` branch, I've branched out of dev E's commit (at the time, the latest) and started developing

```
somethingnew -> A-B-C-D-E
                         \1-2-3
```

However, I noticed that something important was submitted later in `dev` and I require it for my code to work on my own branch as well.

Branch `dev` is now

```
DEV ->  A-B-C-D-E-F-G
```

How can I apply the `F` and `G` before the commits that I currently own in the new feature (before the 1-2-3)

Comment: I assume you didn't need `F` and `G` in `1-2-3`, so why can't you simply merge dev into your branch? The correct answer to your question, however, is to use rebasing but very often people make a mess using rebasing so I try to avoid giving that as a reply until I know it's the only acceptable one.

Comment: can try rebase? though it will rewrite your branch history... it will effectively makes the `F` and `G` before `1`, `2`, `3`. but better off go non-destructive using merge.

Comment: when you are on branch `somethingnew` just do `git rebase dev` or `git pull -r origin dev`. Note the history will be rewritten so you have to be careful if you share branch `somethingnew` with someone else.

Comment: You guys are indeed correct, i tried imagining if rebase would work on this scenario but I thought I'd ask before I attempted anything, thank you all. I'm the only one on this branch, dev is a shared branch. It is indeed local and rewriting history is not bigdeal in this case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `somethingnew` is a local branch and not shared with other developers, you can do a [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

1. Validate that you are on branch `somethingnew` (or run `git checkout somethingnew`)
2. `git rebase dev`

If commits `F` and `G` modify dependencies of commits `1`, `2`, or `3`, you will have to resolve merge conflicts.

Note: If `somethingnew` has already been pushed, doing a `rebase` will force you to have to `force push` the branch.  This should be a coordinated effort with your team, unless you are sure that you are the only developer using the branch.